# What to use to store a list of version numbers in ruby array/hash/set?

Tags: ruby

I want to get a ordered list of my software releases based on each release we have is in a releases folder. ie `/releases/7.1`, `/releases/7.2`, etc

```
# Regexp out the number from the filename
def get_version(filename)
  [0,0] # obviously returns different numbers based on regx
  # {:major => 0, :minor => 0}  # or was thinking about a Hash?
end

versions = [] 
#versions = Array.new() # Is this better? 

Dir.new(basedir).entries.each do |filename|
  versions << get_version(filename) if not File.directory? filename
end

versions.each {|major, minor| puts "#{major}.#{minor}" }
```

Gives me my list

```
7.5
7.8
7.9
4.10
7.3
7.11
7.2
7.4
7.6
7.1
7.10
```

But now I want to order them to look something like this :-

```
4.10
7.1
7.2
7.3
7.4
7.5
7.6
7.8
7.9
7.10  # I appreciate that these might appear below 7.1, I dont mind too much about that
7.11
```

And what about `Symbol`s?!

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, probably I'm missing the point of the question. But why not using sort method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you collect versions in another array and sort it before printing?

```
versions_array = Dir.new(basedir).entries.map do |filename|
  get_version(filename) unless File.directory? filename
end
versions_array.compact!
versions = versions_array.map {|major, minor| "#{major}.#{minor}" }
puts version.sort { |a, b| a.to_f <=> b.to_f }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [versionomy](https://github.com/dazuma/versionomy) gem. Or if you don't want to use gem create your own class and mix in comparable module and implement version comparison (there are a lot of questions on SO regarding how to do this)